# Pass static class reference to a constructor of non-static class

Tags: java, swing

I need to have a reference to the Client because I need to invoke a `setWinTitle` to change the title of current window. How to fix it?

```
    public class Client { 
        public static void main(String[] args){
            JPanel gui= startGUI();
            ...
        }

        private static JPanel startGUI(){
            f = new JFrame();
            JPanel gui = new JPanel(this); // error
        }

        public void setWinTitle(String tite){
            f.setTitle(tite);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class JPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    Client client;

    public JPanel(Client cl) {
        client= cl; 
        initComponents();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I think it's confusing to name one of your classes JPanel; I'd change it to something more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Client`:

```
JPanel gui = new JPanel(new Client());
```

Comment: When new *Client* is created, won't it be constructed and then enter it's *main*?

Comment: @RCola - no: you can invoke as many instances of a class (e.g. "Client") as you want, even though it has exactly *one* "static main()" method.  ALSO: an alternative solution might be `JPanel gui = new JPanel()`

Comment: @RCola: `main()` isn't invoked when you create an object.  Rather, `main()` is invoked once (and only once) by the Java Virtual Machine when it starts your application.  The JVM does not instantiate the object containing the `main()` method - it does not need to because the `main()` method is static.